# Jquery: Get Month between 2 dates

Tags: jquery, datetime

I have 2 different dates and I would like to get the month from these two dates

```
var from = '08-01-2016';
var to = '10-01-2016';
```

I want 2 different months from these dates. Please help.

Comment: What exactly you want?Do you want the moth difference between dates?

Comment: yes i want the return 2 moth difference between dates

Comment: `08-01-2016` is invalid format, you cannot convert it into date directly. is this the format you get.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var past_date = new Date('08-01-2016');
var current_date = new Date('10-01-2016');

var difference = (current_date.getFullYear()*12 + current_date.getMonth()) - (past_date.getFullYear()*12 + past_date.getMonth());
   console.log("Month Difference : " +difference);
```